# I created a Ubuntu USB drive can I actually install it without messing with Windows 10

Tags: operating-system

I bought a PC which comes with Windows 10 and I have a lot of work done on it. I put Ubuntu on my USB stick, then tried to run it and it worked. So my question is... Since it asked me to Try it or Install it... If I install it will it erase Windows 10? Cause my primary OS needs to be Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can if you overwrite the partition Windows is on.

I suspect the installer will explicitly give you the option to automagically install Ubuntu in a dual boot configuration. But if it does not, then you might need to resize your windows partition to create free space for your linux partitions.

See 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Thank you. Btw bonus question if possible.. Can I use one usb for multiple os's? I will accept this answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: Sure, you could run multiple OS's off of your USB stick. If your intention is just to run Ubuntu off your live stick, then you don't need to dual boot either.

Comment: So if I install Linux mint and Ubuntu how would I make one active and not the other?